# separate one CSV row into multiple rows based on contents of a single cell

Tags: powershell, csv

I based my own solution on  [How to separate one row into multiple rows based on a single cell containing multiple values in the same row in a CSV file using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37594954/how-to-separate-one-row-into-multiple-rows-based-on-a-single-cell-containing-mul)

Trying to iterate over one row, retrieve the zips, split it by ' ' and create a new PSCustomObject for each using the zipcodes and place the zipcode in the column with new rows in the same csv.

Sample (yes, hood = no value)

```
City,State,hood,zip,lat,lng
Carmel,IN,,"46290 46032 46033 46280 46082",39.9783711,-86.1180435
```

My non working solution is a modification of the solution in the link sited

```
$x = Get-Content 'D:\Carmel-IN.csv'
$y = $x | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' '
$y | Foreach {
    $current = $_
    $current.zip -split ' ' | foreach  {
        [PSCUstomObject]@{ 
            zip  = $_
        }
    }
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ' ' | % {
    $_ -replace '"',''
}
```

The output is the same on ISE and console ... the one word `zip` and nothing  is written to file.

I am very new to PS, using 5.1.  I have a feeling the correction is very simple but I cant see it. Looking for a result file as ...

```
City,State,hood,zip,lat,lng
Carmel,IN,,"46290 46032 46033 46280 46082",39.9783711,-86.1180435
,,,46290,,
,,,46032,,
,,,46033,,
,,,46280,,
,,,46082,,
```

**UPDATE:**

I managed to rework the script to get result I can use

```
$x = Get-Content 'D:\temp\Carmel-IN.csv'
$exportlocation = 'D:\temp\Carmel-IN.csv'
$y = $x | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ','
$y | Foreach {
    $current = $_
    $current.zip -split ' ' | foreach  {
        [PSCUstomObject]@{ 
            City  = $null
            State = $null
            hood  = $null
            zip   = $_
            lat   = $null
            lng   = $null
        }
    } 
} | Export-CSV -Append -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ',' -Force $exportlocation  | % { $_ -replace '"',''}
```

and the result is

```
City,State,hood,zip,lat,lng
Carmel,IN,,"46290 46032 46033 46280 46082",39.9783711,-86.1180435
,,,"46290",,
,,,"46032",,
,,,"46033",,
,,,"46280",,
,,,"46082",,
```

I am going to care of the extra "'s in another script

The   `| % { $_ -replace '"',''}` doesn't seem to be removing them

Thanks for all suggestions

Comment: What is your ultimate desire. That file that you show as your desired output, while technically correct CSV, is I suspect not the best way to handle your data. I suspect that XML, JSON, or some other structured data storage method would be better

Comment: Ooh, that data commits the cardinal sin: storing multiple values in a single column.

Comment: @EBGreen  While that maybe correct, this week is my first foray into ANY type of scripting (beyond use of iMacros that I stopped using almost 3 years ago), after an 'expert' at fiverr took a week to finally giveup saying he wsnt able to do my project for me. This is the second of 5 scripts I will have to write. Hopefully data will be able to eventually find its way into MySQL, and I can also learn to use that tool.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn    lol ... well .. my excuse is I have to use the data the way I found it and proceed with caution from there  ;-)

Comment: Please do not edit an answer into a question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Select-Object`:

```
$x = Get-Content 'D:\Carmel-IN.csv'
$y = $x | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' '
foreach($row in $y){
  foreach($zip in -split $row.zip){
    $row |select *,@{Name='zip';Expression={$zip}} -ExcludeProperty zip
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to preserve the order of columns, set up the property list of properties to select prior to the loop:

```
$columns = $y[0].psobject.Properties.Name |ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -eq 'zip'){
        $_ = @{Name = 'zip';Expression = { -split $zip }}
    }
    $_
}
foreach($row in $y){
  foreach($zip in -split $row.Zip){
    $row |select $columns
  }
}
```

Comment: When I try your script all I get is the first value in the cell '46290' and the remainder are ignored. Also the 'lat' and 'lng' are completely ignored. Am I missing something in the explanation?

Comment: I truly appreciate all the solutions you have provided to many questions here on the forum: I have learned much that I have put to use in other scripts and am sure I will continue to do so ... kudos from a newbie !!