# In batch data doesn't get from CSV to be processed, singly is processed

Tags: powershell, csv

This follows on my last question, to which I developed a working script as an answer [Powershell- separate one csv row into multiple rows based on contents of a single cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49349185/powershell-separate-one-csv-row-into-multiple-rows-based-on-contents-of-a-singl)

Now I am attempting to just get a whole folder processed instead of a single file (all the files are formatted the same as per my original question), and there are files produced in the output folder but they have no data. The `$files = Get-ChildItem` procedure I have done successfully in other script, and the way the data is processed is the same as in the previous question (shown here for the single file)

```
$x = Get-Content 'D:\temp\Carmel-IN.csv'
$exportlocation = 'D:\temp\Carmel-IN.csv'
$y = $x | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ','
$y | Foreach {
    $current = $_
    $current.zip -split ' ' | foreach {
        [PSCUstomObject]@{ 
            City  = $null
            State = $null
            hood  = $null
            zip   = $_
            lat   = $null
            lng   = $null
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Append -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ',' -Force $exportlocation | % {
    $_ -replace '"',''
}
```

**BUT** trying to accomplish same with batch of files only gives me empty files in the destination directory. Thinking it was the `" $y = $($file.Name) "` change, I also tried `" $y = $file.Name "`  and `" $y = $file "` with the same results.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem 'D:\!__DATA for searches\tempDataForECLsw\*.csv' 

# Loop through each file
foreach ($file in $files) { 
    # Imports CSV file, selects desired zip data, and then exports as CSV to the desired destination
    $y = $($file.Name) | ConvertFrom-Csv 
    $y | ForEach-Object {
        $current = $_
        $current.zip -split ' ' | foreach {
            [PSCUstomObject]@{ 
                City  = $null
                State = $null
                hood  = $null
                zip   = $_
                lat   = $null
                lng   = $null
            }
        }
    } | Export-Csv -Path "D:\!__DATA for searches\tempECL\$($file.Name)" -Append -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ',' -Force | % {
        $_ -replace '"',''
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think your second code snippet would work *without* `Get-Content`? And why are you using `Get-Content` and `ConvertFrom-Csv` instead of `Import-Csv` in the first place?

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers This is a modification of the very second script I have written in PS5, which I only started self learning 3 days ago. Excuse me if I didnt think of everything. This is not like the daily dose of marketing I learn everyday. I do appreciate the hint. All of this is much, MUCH, different from the FORTRAN I played with in high school: not that I can recall any of it other than punching out 100 feet of paper tape.

Comment: `Get-Conent` and `Import-Csv` are basic commands that should be covered by any sensible PowerShell tutorial.